# How would someone go about calculating the probability of the unlikely scenario where to friends meet on their vacation?

Tags: probability

Imagine this. Robert goes on vacation. Upon his arrival at the destination, he is unexpectedly greeted by a good friend of him, Jeremy. Weirdly enough, they happened to go on the same trip, be neighbors at the site, at the same time and place, and for the same duration. Keep in mind, none of them knew of the other's plan. I know the math is close to impossible, for the amount of details to account for is just overwhelming. But, I think it would be interesting if we can find a sort of approximation for this kind of scenario (or have some sort of universal probability). Let's say this: Robert and Jeremy are best friends, there are about 300 houses for rental, they went on vacation for a whole week and it's summer.

Comment: This answer to a closely related (closed) question may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898661/probability-of-two-people-from-two-different-countries-meeting-in-a-different-co/2898671#2898671

Comment: Before looking at the probability of this specific scenario... it is worth pointing out and reminding that *coincidences happen all the time*.  It is just that the coincidences that *do* happen are far more noticeable than the huge number that *don't* happen.  It is in some ways stranger that *nothing* coincidental happens.